# python v.3.4.2 cryptography systems

Tags: encryption

does anybody know how to encrypt ***and*** decrypt using python3.4  [shell](http://python.org/shell/)

cos i was wondering why people have been creating cryptographic lists then inputting them into python.

The lists look something like this:

(lp0

S'a'

p1

aI123

a(lp2

I4

aI5

aI01

aa.

apparently this makes ['a', 123, True] when decrypted.
How do they get that list?

Comment: You can use Python to implement pretty much any encryption algorithm you please. Determining what encryption the above ciphertext uses is off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you posted is not encrypted, but [serialized](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). This is **not** a form of cryptography and does not preserve confidentiality of the serialized objects.

The python standard library does not support encryption/decryption. However, it is a [turing complete language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), and any algorithm can be implemented in it.  It is possible to serialize an object(s), and then encrypt the resultant byte stream.

Note that the pickle itself is potentially a source of [arbitrary code injection](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Slaviero/BH_US_11_Slaviero_Sour_Pickles_WP.pdf). If you intend to use pickled objects, you will need integrity and authentication verification, which can be obtained from a [message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).

Comment: ok! i got it! i can't use cryptography with pickle on python.